# send a javascript request to another domain and get the response - not in jsonp

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonp

i am really banging my head here for more then a day, i am trying to send a request and get the response from another site. i'm doing it with jsonp (from the obvious reason). but the response is not a JavaScript function definition, so it keeps failing.

can anyone in this planet help me get the response the right way.

i attached the code i wrote, again: because the response is not in json it's not working. (try to run it yourself and you'll see).

any suggestions?

```
<script>
function test()
{
  $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
      url: 'https://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?viewer=1000009843914&token=1-1&filter[0]=user&options[0]=pending_request&lazy=1&token=v7&stale_ok=1&__a=1&__user=1000009843914&    viewer=1000009843914',
  });
}
function jsonp_callback(data)
{

 var val=JSON.stringify(data);
 myString = val.slice( 11 );
 $('#container').html(myString);

/*for (;;);*/
 }
 test();
</script>
```

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear. JSONp works fine with a non-JSON payload, but the server must wrap the content in a JavaScript function definition that returns the data when called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: hey steve, can you please explain a little bit more.
how can i create this request so that it will be success even dow it's not a json response?

Answer (score 0):

The server must be programmed to include the JSONP callback within its script file. If it only knows to return JSON, it will have no effect when the dynamic script tag is inserted into the page since JSON can at most provide an object--but it won't go anywhere unless the same file calls the function. In this way, it is different from Ajax, since a dynamically inserted script tag can only interact with your own code if it knows to call one of your functions. Just as an example, it might return:

```
jsonp_callback({facebooKData:[...]});
```

You should investigate how the Facebook API supports JSONP (not just JSON) for whatever you are trying to do. Typically APIs will accept a "callback" variable to determine which callback function it should use (which jQuery handles for you).